# Monitor memory usage per thread

Tags: java, memory, profiling, jmx, visualvm

How can I monitor an application's memory usage per thread?
I tried VisualVM but it says that memory sampling is not available.
What else can I try? (Note I am using IBM JDK)

Comment: Would exactly do you mean by "per thread". The thread's stack size? Because the heap is shared between all threads and probably very difficult to piece apart.

Comment: @Thilo:Yes if possible heap or else how the heap is divided for threads

Comment: All the memory is accessible to all the threads. Only the stack is truly thread local.  If you want to monitor which code is creating the most objects I suggest using a commercial memory profiler such as YourKit (an eval license is free)

Comment: @Jim - Thilo is saying that the heap is NOT divided for threads.  They all use the same heap.  Threads can share objects, directly or indirectly, there is not way to decide which thread "owns" what.

Comment: @StephenC:So if I see heavy memory usage, how do I know which thread is responsible for that?

Comment: @PeterLawrey:So it is possible only using commercial tools?So not to waste time trying `MAT` or any other? I also see `JConsole` does not offer this

Comment: With Yourkit (and other commercial profilers) you can find in seconds what you might take an hour or so with jmap style tools. JConsole will only give you a total usage. Even VisualVM is better than JConsole (as its newer) The commercial profilers are not cheap but you can get an eval license for them for long enough to solve your problem. I was using commercial profilers on and off for years before I bought a license ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey:Just to make sure.You are saying that it may be possible but a lot harder to find this info from other tools?Should I try `jmap` or I shouldn't bother?

Comment: I wouldn't bother unless you want to get rid of any hair you have left ;)

Comment: I realize this is old, but with a Oracle 1.7 VM, using VisualVM Sampling DOES show per-thread memory allocations. It shows a table of total allocated bytes per thread, as well as the current allocation rate in bytes/second. You can't examine what objects are being created in that thread, but it can help highlight a thread that will help you to track down the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YourKit is the simplest option

Answer (score 2):

Use [jconsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/jconsole.html) that is in your JAVA_HOME\bin or [JVM Monitor](http://www.jvmmonitor.org/index.html) tool.